# c++ Proper position for 'using namespace'

Tags: c++, namespaces

I was integrating some C++ in somelse's one and found out we adopt two
different strategies regarding the use of **using namespace** commands.

For cleanliness of source code, which of the two is the most correct solution?

```
namespace foo
{
   using namespace bar;
}
```

or

```
using namespace bar;

namespace foo
{
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help,

T.

Answer (score 7):

The two are not equivalent. In the first case the namespace `bar` is imported in the namespace `foo` so for every `bar::x` you can access it as `foo::x`. In the latter the namespace `bar` is imported in the global namespace (or the namespace that wraps both up) and it can be accessed as `::x`.

I'd recommend to always choose the narrowest possible solution for you. Even to the point of including the namespace only in the function you actually need it. So if you are in doubt go with the first one.

Comment: +1 for "narrowest possible".  I almost never write `using namespace` - it's almost always better to use only the specific names you want from the namespace.

Comment: @TobySpeight Sure. Exceptions to this are namespaces like `std::literals` or `std::placeholders` which are designed to be included in its entirety.

Comment: @Jefffrey agreed, although because boost got there first, even std::placeholders can be a minefield. std::literals is about the only safe one.

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered, but I want to reiterate the point mooted by `Toby Speight`.
 One should never write something like `using namespace bar`.

Good practice is to use `using` as a aliasing aid for long/hierarchial `namespaces`. Like

```
using po = boost::program_options;
```

And then use

```
po.notify(vm);
```

Either of two alternatives suggested in question are only good for discussions or interviews.

Comment: "One should never write something like `using namespace bar`". I disagree entirely. Certain namespaces are meant to be imported with `using namespace`. Just like pretty much any other absolute you can stick to programming, there are always exceptions.

Comment: I am reiterating the point discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: My question is not answered in that discussion.
I was asking about the best practice among the 2, not whether one of them was to consider as a bad one

Comment: "I'd recommend to always choose the narrowest possible solution for you" -- clearly says first option is better, if you really need to import a namespace.